MariaDB fails to start after upgraded
I'm in panic, I have upgraded mariadb to 11.5.1 on CentOS 7 but it keeps failing when trying to start:
systemctl status mariadb gives me:
[root@izk1aaur2shmpokx2h15i1z etc]# systemctl status mariadb
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.4.34 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-08-09 19:53:41 WIB; 2min 37s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 4800 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Process: 4684 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4682 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4800 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 09 19:53:41 izk1aaur2shmpokx2h15i1z systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.4.34 database server...
Aug 09 19:53:41 izk1aaur2shmpokx2h15i1z systemd[4800]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/mysqld: Too many levels of symbolic links
Aug 09 19:53:41 izk1aaur2shmpokx2h15i1z systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 09 19:53:41 izk1aaur2shmpokx2h15i1z systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.4.34 database server.
Aug 09 19:53:41 izk1aaur2shmpokx2h15i1z systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Aug 09 19:53:41 izk1aaur2shmpokx2h15i1z systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
[root@izk1aaur2shmpokx2h15i1z etc]#


The error message Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/mysqld: Too many levels of symbolic links indicates that the system is attempting to execute the mysqld binary but is encountering a circular symlink.
So, to fix it you need to first check:
ls -l /usr/sbin/mysqld

If I'm right that's a circular symlink, then remove it:
rm /usr/sbin/mysqld

Recreate the correct symlink:
ln -s /usr/sbin/mysqld_safe /usr/sbin/mysqld

Finally, restart mariadb:
systemctl restart mariadb

You can read about mysqld_safe here to suit your system if I didn't guess the right match.
Good luck!
